# Class member is inaccesible due to it's protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have created a class `ENNumber` which I am attempting to map to a database field. When I try to link the two in my map, I get the error that the expression is inaccessible due to it's protection level.

I've ensured that my class members are public, and anywhere I've referenced it otherwise is also public.

```cs
public class ENNumber
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ENNumber_QRFItem> ENNumQrfItem { get; set; }
  }
```

```cs
public class QRF1896 : Emailable
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Decimal? Temperature { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Decimal? Humidity { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "EN Number")]
    public virtual ENNumber ENNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Valid temperature")]
    [Required]
    public bool ValidTemp { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Valid humidity")]
    [Required]
    public bool ValidHumidity { get; set; }

    public string Updated_Username { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Updated_Timestamp { get; set; }
  }
```

```cs
public class QRF1896Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<QRF1896>
  {
    public QRF1896Map()
    {
      this.HasKey<int>((Expression<Func<QRF1896, int>>) (t => t.Id));
      this.Property((Expression<Func<QRF1896, string>>) (t => t.Username)).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(new int?(50));
      this.ToTable("QRF1896");
      this.Property<int>((Expression<Func<QRF1896, int>>) (t => t.Id)).HasColumnName("Id");
      this.Property((Expression<Func<QRF1896, DateTime>>) (t => t.Timestamp)).HasColumnName("Timestamp");
      this.Property((Expression<Func<QRF1896, Decimal?>>) (t => t.Temperature)).HasColumnName("Temperature");
      this.Property((Expression<Func<QRF1896, Decimal?>>) (t => t.Humidity)).HasColumnName("Humidity");
      this.Property((Expression<Func<QRF1896, string>>) (t => t.ENNumber.Name)).HasColumnName("ENNum"); // <- error here
      this.Property((Expression<Func<QRF1896, string>>) (t => t.Username)).HasColumnName("Username");
      this.Property<bool>((Expression<Func<QRF1896, bool>>) (t => t.ValidTemp)).HasColumnName("ValidTemp");
      this.Property<bool>((Expression<Func<QRF1896, bool>>) (t => t.ValidHumidity)).HasColumnName("ValidHumidity");
    }
  }
```

The actual error is:

```
Error   1   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StructuralTypeConfiguration<QRF.Db.Models.QRF1896>.Property<TPrimitivePropertyConfiguration>(System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Comment: Is `ENNumber_QRFItem` public, too?

Comment: @kara yes, the declaration for that class is `public class ENNumber_QRFItem`

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me in the end was just cleaning/rebuilding my solution in VS. Who knew? :P